# Android LiveData<List<User>> cast to LiveData<List<?extednds IEntity>>

Tags: android, generic-list, android-livedata

I have generic problem,

I have **LiveData<List<User>>**, object **User** implement **IEntity**.

How to cast **LiveData<List<User>>** to **LiveData<List<IEntity>>**?

```
  package cz.roomlivedata.entity;
  import  android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
  import android.arch.persistence.room.Index; 
  import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;

  @Entity(indices = {@Index(value = "id", unique = true)}) 
  public class User implements IEntity {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) public int id;

  private String name;

  private String name; public User(String name) { this.name = name; } 

  public String getName() { return name; } 

  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; } 
}
```

[image: code]

Comment: add User class code

Comment: You say that "User *implements* IEntity" not "... *extends* IEntitiy".  But without the latter, you can't add anything from one List to the other

Comment: @Radesh
`<pre>package cz.roomlivedata.entity;

import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Index;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = "id", unique = true)})
public class User implements IEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}</pre>`

Comment: @motorcb did your problem solved?

Comment: This is a good question sadly with no good answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how I removed while using kotlin.

```
abstract class X

class Y: X()

fun getValues(): MutableLiveData<out List<X>> {
    return MutableLiveData<List<Y>>()
}
```

`out` keyword helped me. So basically what `in` and `out` keyword does have to be done in java manually.

Comment: Where to put this, what's `out`. this does not explain anything